# BigQuery - PIVOT with declared ARRAY

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Pivoting like this works

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE SOF_SAMPLE
    AS  SELECT 1 id, 'BANANA' fruit, 2 value
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'ORANGE', 10
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'APPLE', 3;
END;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, VALUE, FRUIT
  FROM `SOF_SAMPLE`
  WHERE 
    1=1
    AND FRUIT IN ('BANANA', 'APPLE')
)
PIVOT (
  AVG(VALUE)
  FOR FRUIT IN ('BANANA', 'APPLE')
)
```

However it seems that `PIVOT .. FOR i IN` does not accept `UNNEST` (`Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at`)

```
DECLARE FRUITS ARRAY <STRING> DEFAULT ['BANANA', 'APPLE'];

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, VALUE, FRUIT
  FROM `SOF_SAMPLE`
  WHERE 
    1=1
    AND FRUIT IN UNNEST(FRUITS)
)
PIVOT (
  AVG(VALUE)
  FOR FRUIT IN UNNEST(FRUITS)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to use an array as pivot columns, so most general way to to is to write a dynamic sql. Consider below query.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ID, VALUE, FRUIT FROM `SOF_SAMPLE` WHERE FRUIT IN ('%s')
)
PIVOT (AVG(VALUE) FOR FRUIT IN ('%s'))
"""
, ARRAY_TO_STRING(FRUITS, "','")
, (SELECT STRING_AGG(FRUITS, "','") FROM SOF_SAMPLE));
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to use UNNEST(FRUITS) in the WHERE clause ?

Comment: @J.Doe, I don't think so.  it should be used along with **FROM** clause.

Comment: it is possible to use UNNEST(FRUITS) in the WHERE clause using ARRAY_TO_STRING(FRUITS, "','")

Comment: yes, you can use **ARRAY_TO_STRING()** in **WHERE** clause, but not along with **UNNEST()**.